# I need to make following link in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I need to make following link from page, my XML is:

```
<div class="paginator bottom">
<div class="pager"><!-- Numbered page links -->
<div class="page active"><b>1</b></div>
<div class="page"><a href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=2">2</a></div>
<div class="page"><a href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=3">3</a></div>
<div class="page"><a href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=4">4</a></div>
<div class="page"><a href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=5">5</a></div>
<div class="page"><a href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=6">6</a></div>
<div class="page"><a href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=7">7</a></div>
<div class="page"><a href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=8">8</a></div>
<div class="page">...</div>
<div class="page"><a class="" href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=107">107</a></div>
<div class="page"><a class="next" href="?=&amp;display=compact&amp;district=&amp;city=&amp;page=2">&gt;</a></div>
</div>
```

so we can see, actually I am on page 1. Now I need to get link on page 2... then if I am on page 8, i need to get link on page 9...

My XSLT is something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="//xhtml:div[@class = 'pager']" mode="next">

<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>

<xsl:variable name="url" select="//xhtml:div[@class = 'pager']"/>

<xsl:variable name="url1" select="normalize-space(substring-after($url,'div class="page active"'))"/>

<next>
<xsl:variable name="url" select="$url1f"/>
</next>

</xsl:template>
```

Of course its not workong, this line:

```
 <xsl:variable name="url1" select="normalize-space(substring-after($url,'div class="page active"'))"/>
```

can't be OK.

Some help please?

Answer (score 0):

ou... i got it...

i don't look at the last div... and here is answer

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//xhtml:div[@class = 'pager']/xhtml:div[@class = 'page'][last()]" mode="next"/>
```